# FTP opendir() — "FTP server reports 550 [can't find file]"

Tags: php, ftp

I am attempting to read a open a directory using `opendir()`, and then loop through the files in that directory. The ultimate goal for this script is to transfer certain files from the directory that is being read to a different FTP server.

The "FTP" part is what's screwing me up—and I have no idea why!

---

**On some servers (this script is expected to be run across several) I am receiving the following error:**

```
Warning: opendir(ftp://...@jslsolutions2.flashsvr.com/streaming)
[function.opendir]: failed to open dir: FTP server reports 550
Can't find file in [PATH] on line 88
```

[PATH] would be the actual path to the PHP script, of course.

---

**Line 88 is as follows:**

```
if ($handle = opendir($from))
```

The variable `$from` represents a complete FTP path.

---

**The complete FTP path is as follows:**

```
 ftp://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[SERVER]/streaming
```

---

I have confirmed that directory is correct. When I copy and paste the directory into my web browser, for example, Firefox opens a directory tree containing all of the files, exactly as expected. In other words, though PHP is complaining that it "can't find file", the "file" (that is the directory, I believe) actually does exist.

What on earth is going on? As I mentioned before, this script does work on some servers. The thing holding it up appears to be whether or not the server is Windows-based, as it works fine on the Linux servers I have tested. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the servers, though our server administrator can make changes if we can isolate the problem.

**Why am I receiving this error, and is there a workaround?**

Comment: you should to look into `ftp_connect` if adding a trailing / doesn't help http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Add a trailing slash / see if that resolves the issue there was a bug in PHP which has been fixed.